# Which data type should send to AMQP broker (like RabbitMQ)

Tags: architecture, message-queue, messaging

I can't decide this. Should I sent only just database row ID or full database object as a message to RabbitMQ. The first choice is good for queueing but require to fetch database rows to process it again.

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question, also check the checklist at http://tinyurl.com/cjk2hnx

Answer (score 0):

The first option works *only* by virtue of the fact that both endpoints share (or have access to) the same database. This will be a limiting factor in the future if you are moving towards a distributed design or wish to segregate your data sources in the SOA manner.

Sending the entire model object would usually be preferable as it shields consumers from the database implementation details.